# How to run a simple click event on a div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a simple click event but can't get it working.
If I remove the callback it works, but on load not on click.

Does anyone know what's wrong in my code?

**script.js**

```
const green = document.getElementById('green');

const clickColor = () => {
  alert('This is green color');
}

green.onclick = () => clickColor();
```

Comment: I actually just tested this and it seems to work fine.

Comment: How does your function _know_ what colour your element is?

Answer (score -1):

You could add a class to the element you're clicking on, and have the function pick that up.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', clickColor, false);

function clickColor() {
  const c = this.className;
  console.log(`This is ${c}`);
}
```

```css
button { color: white; }
.green { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<button class="green">Green</button>
```

Comment: The question was regarding code that doesn't work. No mention was made in the OP of trying to figure out the color.

Comment: Yes. But I'm a senior dev. And urging younger devs to take a look at their code and try to understand it is part of my job, and the reason this site is around. The code wasn't right, but the thinking behind it wasn't right either. @Cjmarkham